# WPF not rendering properly

Tags: wpf

I'm I'm currently making a wpf c# app. I have some storyboards which animate some elements. Please look at the picture below:

[image]

This is my grid with some controls after it has been animated. Notice the improper rendering of the text and the rectangle. How can I solve this rendering?

UPDATE: Code request by Rachel:

```
<TextBlock Height="35.667" Margin="73.667,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="32" Foreground="Black" Text="close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="73.667" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>

    <Rectangle x:Name="BS2" Fill="#FF0178D3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64.166" Margin="25,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30.667" StrokeThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that makes that image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried testing it on several different machines? WPF can be sensitive to differences in graphics cards.

Comment: Agree with this. I've had something look perfectly clear and easy to read on my machine, but be really blurry and an eyesore on someone elses machine.

Comment: Allright I guess I'll have to live with this then. However I do find it strange that some of the text or rectangles in a grid show this problem and others don't

Comment: I've seen differences between machines bought in the same shipment from Dell with the exact same model of graphics card! One machine displays large text fine, the other has "ragged" edges on the text. I put a new graphics card in the faulty machine, and it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try UseLayoutRounding and SnapsToDevicePixels = true

Edit:

I'm curios how does it look like when you do something like

```
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.01" ScaleY="1.01" />
```

Also you could try wrap it in some other panel (Canvas f.e.)

Comment: I had similar problem under .Net 3.5. In .Net 4.0 with these it looks fine. also you could update drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `TextOptions.TextRenderingMode` and see if that makes a difference. The results vary per machine.

Comment: Tried all options but nothing changes